# Opening Internet Explorer in Private Mode with Selenium Python

Tags: python, selenium, internet-explorer

I am trying to open gmail in IE using selenium in python, after the first time of logging in however, I stay logged in, this breaks my code, and I would like it to start in private mode to make sure I don't stay logged in. This is my code:

```
import time
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys


class internet_explorer:
    def __init__(self):
        self.driver = webdriver.Ie(executable_path='venv\\Scripts\\IEDriverServer.exe')
        self.driver.get("https://gmail.com")
        time.sleep(2)
        self.driver.find_element_by_xpath("//input[@name=\"identifier\"]") \
            .send_keys(em + Keys.ENTER)
        time.sleep(1)
        self.driver.find_element_by_xpath("//input[@name=\"password\"]") \
            .send_keys(pw + Keys.ENTER)
        time.sleep(10)
        self.driver.close()
        self.driver.quit()

internet_explorer()
```

Help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest you can try to refer to an example below to launch the IE browser in private mode.

```
caps = DesiredCapabilities.INTERNETEXPLORER
caps["se:ieOptions"] = {}
caps["se:ieOptions"]['ie.forceCreateProcessApi'] = True
caps["se:ieOptions"]['ie.browserCommandLineSwitches'] ='-private'
caps["se:ieOptions"]["ie.ensureCleanSession"] = True
driver = webdriver.Ie(executable_path='C:\selenium\IEDriverServer_x64_3_8.exe', capabilities=caps)
```

If the issue persists then please try to provide detailed information about the issue like which IE version, Selenium version you are using , etc.

Comment: This worked! I had to take out the ```caps["se:ieOptions"]['ie.forceCreateProcessApi'] = True'``` line, because otherwise it crashed. Thanks!

Comment: Did not work for me.